# Neo4j cypher query simulate sql join query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two different kinds of node entities without any relationships between them, i wonder how to write a cypher query to join these two node entities by common property?

For example, if i want to return a blog by passing blogId as a parameter, but i also want to return creator username by joining user entity. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible, sure. Are you're nodes indexed? Do you use Neo4j 2.0 and labels, or do you use 1.9? Look at this (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-sql-match.html) and at the pages just before and after from the docs, and say something more about how you usually get nodes from the database (index, labels, neo4j version) and I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: Looks like it has to be a relationship between notes

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you have a relationship between user and blog? As far as graph dbs are concerned to connect data, this will help you to get users' blogs. Further, you can connect the blogs according to their topics etc.

Comment: I have two databases in my project, mysql and neo4j. Try to add as less as possible info in neo4j, looks like it's not possible to join nodes wothout relationship, thanks for your suggestion, i'll add a relationship between them.

Comment: For your join, it would be like this - didn't compile it though - start n=node(*), m=node(*) where m.has(joinProperty) AND m.has(joinProperty) AND n.joinProperty = m.joinProperty RETURN n,m